# Definition of “degree zero” in the localization of a graded ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, localization, graded-rings

Let $S$ be a graded ring and $f$ is an element of degree $d>0$. Then $S_{(f)}$ is defined as the subring of elements of degree $0$ in the localized ring $S_{f}$ (Hartshorne, pp. 77). But the definition seems to have a problem.

Suppose that the graded ring $S$ is not a domain, and $fy=0$ for some non-zero element $y$. Then $\frac{x+y}{f^n}=\frac{x}{f^n}\in S_f$ for each $x\in S$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. When $\text{deg}(x)=nd\ne \text{deg}(y)$, is the above element included in $S_{(f)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For an element of the localization to be homogeneous of some degree, all that is required is that it *can* be represented by a homogeneous fraction of that degree.  It is not necessary that *every* representation as a fraction is homogeneous of that degree.